# Предлоги в русском языке

Tags: предлоги

Здравствуйте! У меня такой вопрос: как объяснить иностранцу (китайцу) употребление ВРЕМЕННОГО предлога "НА"?

Answer (score 2):

1) Значение временных предлогов можно понять, если сначала рассмотреть **предметно-пространственные отношения**: положить книгу **в стол, на стол** (В.п.), книга лежит **в столе, на столе** (П.п.).

2) Потом переходим **к временному пространству:** положить **на стол** (пространственный предмет) ― отложить **на утро** (отрезок времени), встретиться **в  5 часов** (точка во времени) ― назначить **на 5 часов** (время как ориентир).

3) Основным значением В.п. является направленность, точность, а П.п. ― ненаправленный, неопределенный, поэтому: встретимся **на днях, на неделе (П.п.)**.

Answer (score 2):

Трудность восприятия предлога НА во временном значении состоит 
в том, что в китайском  предлоги однозначны,"НА" у них – 
пространственный предлог, а временные – из, с, от-до, по мере, при.
 Видимо, следует сказать, что предлог "НА" указывает на связь со словом "отрезок", а отрезок может означать и пространство, и время.

Временное значение предлога НА появляется при обозначении срока, 
времени, с наступлением которого совершается или должно произойти 
что- либо, при указании срока, на который распространяются результаты
 какого-либо действия, при обозначении срока, непосредственно 
следующего за чем-л. и отрезка времени, к одному из моментов которого приурочивается происходящее.

Даже на одну минутку он не остановился.

Он отложил это на осень.

Это было ночью с одиннадцатого на двенадцатое января.

Отец ездил в деревню только на праздники.